# Powershell: Saving file to root

Tags: powershell, root

I'm running a powershell file which are going to gather information an save it to an XML-file. This script will run on several computers, and so I want to save them all to a rootpath. The question is, how do I save an XML-file to root on a computer?

To specify: The script will always run on a local computer, hence I need to save the xml file to a local path..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly..
If you have access to the root drive of the computers in question... this will save each xml file, named after its computer name, in the C drive of each computer.

```
"comp1","comp2","comp3" | Foreach-Object {
   $xml = ....
   $xml | Out-File -Path "\\$_\c$\$_.xml"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicly the path to save on a root is:

```
\\servername\c$\myfile.xml
```

This is the path to save in the c:\ root folder of a remote machine.
You need `local administrator credentials` of the server.